# Query on cloud init

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-ami

If I create the custom AMI, (This AMI is imported from VMware server using the import-image) can i use the user data while launching the instance from this AMI?Means cloud-init will be available in the custom AMI using the import-image? OS are RHEL..

Comment: Can you please add the problem you are facing instead of asking not researched questions ?

Answer (score 1):

You would need to install the cloud-init service on the VM you are creating the custom AMI from. That isn't something AWS does for you automatically.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. Is there any option without installing cloud-init on the VM?

Comment: Are you asking if there is any option to use cloud-init on a server without installing cloud-init on that server?

Comment: You could write a bash script that runs everytime when the instance is started. In the bash script, curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/user-data/. Redirect the output of the curl command to a file, change permissions of the file to executable and run the file.

Comment: @KrishnaKumarR that's assuming the user data value is a Bash script. That is only one of many types of input accepted by the cloud-init service.